# algorithms to pick best collection of classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, model

I have a bunch of methods that classify a binary outcome. I'm trying to figure out if some combination of those classifiers is better than any others.

I'm hoping to run a bunch of methods. I've thought of running random forests/cart and perhaps a SVM model.

What are some other common methods typically done for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about whats known as 'ensembling'. I'd suggest reading about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning. Two popular methods are boosting and bagging.